# ActionListener from JTextField values not passed

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jtextfield

I am back at my payroll calculator and I am trying to create an action listener that takes the values from a JTextField.  When I debug it, I can't figure out why the values are not passed. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
package week4Calc;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
/**
 *
 * @author bsmith
 */
public class PayrollDisplay extends JFrame {

    public static JTextField hoursField, rateField;

    public PayrollDisplay() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame ();
        Panel panel1 = new Panel();
        Panel panel2 = new Panel();
        ExitButton exit = new ExitButton ();
        JButton calc = new JButton ("Calculate");
        calc.addActionListener(new calcEvent());


        JLabel nameLbl = new JLabel ("Name:");
        JTextField nameField = new JTextField (10);

        JLabel deptLbl = new JLabel ("Department:");
        EmpDeptBox box1 = new EmpDeptBox ();

        JLabel hoursLbl = new JLabel ("Hours:");
        hoursField = new JTextField (3);

        JLabel rateLbl = new JLabel ("Rate:");
        rateField = new JTextField (7);

        panel1.add(nameLbl);
        panel1.add(nameField);
        panel1.add(deptLbl);
        panel1.add(box1);
        panel1.add(hoursLbl);
        panel1.add(hoursField);
        panel1.add(rateLbl);
        panel1.add(rateField);

        panel2.add(exit);
        panel2.add(calc);

        frame.add(panel1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(panel2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(750,200);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public class calcEvent implements ActionListener
    {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
        {
            float payCheck,hoursWrkd,payRate;
            hoursWrkd = Float.parseFloat(hoursField.toString());
            payRate = Float.parseFloat(rateField.toString());
            payCheck = hoursWrkd*payRate;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The paycheck should be: $"+payCheck);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be using the method `getText()` instead of `toString()` on the fields. Is your action listener firing?

Comment: @Ma3x, yes it is firing and your answer solved my problem.  The method I was calling was wrong.  Thank you!